# how to increase the height equally of two DIV?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to adjust the left div's height automatically  with the right div height increase.

My CSS and HTML code is here

```
.left {
margin:auto;
float:left;
width:30%;
height:auto;
background:#000;
}
.right {
margin:auto;
float:left;
width:70%;
height:auto;
background:#eee;
}

<div class="left">sgdsfhdh</div>
<div class="right">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and     typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this **just by CSS**. You need to use `display:flex;` and need one `div` that wraps your `left` and `right` div/class.

```css
.wrap {
    display:flex;
}
.left {
    width:30%;
    background:#000;
}
.right {
    width:70%;
    background:#eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">sgdsfhdh</div>
    <div class="right">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Also if you still want the **JQuery** way.

http://jsfiddle.net/52xy3gdr/1/

Comment: What's the third div for?

Answer (score -1):

```
var oldheight=$("#right").height();  
  $('#right').bind('resize', function(){
          if($("#right").height()!=oldheight)
           {
            oldheight=$("#right").height();
           $('#left').css("height","30px");
            }
        });
```